# Second Ethernet for control

Tags: networking

I'm trying to set up a web server that will have a public facing IP with only the necessary ports open. As it would be nice to still control it from within my network, is Overtime possible to use the second Ethernet connection to have local SSH access from within my other network?  The cards would be on different subnets, and I would like to limit access on the second card by IP. Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can have more than one network interface on a host at the same time with one external and one internal.  At my job we do it all the time.  The internal we use for controlling or building the server.  All you need to do is specify what networks they will be attached to.  The host will do the rest.

See examples in this answer here:

[How do I configure two network adapters in Ubuntu Server?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/76065/how-do-i-configure-two-network-adapters-in-ubuntu-server)

To allow a specific IP address to access the host, you would need to set it up with IP Tables.  Here is a nice little "how to" for configuring IP Tables:

http://safesrv.net/quick-how-to-denyallow-ip-using-iptables/

**NOTE:** with the above "how to" you can specify what interface you are blocking or allowing on by putting in `-i eth0` or `-i eth1`